# revert view option is missing

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I have exported my view, and I want to revert the same in other site environment; the revert view option is missing. Am I missing anything?

I am using Drupal 7 and Views 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in "admin/structure/views", click the little arrow next to "edit" link under Operations column. If your view has changed from what's exported in code, it should display "revert" option there.